# HOG features for different image sizes and different aspect ratios

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am using opencv and HOG features for image classification but one problem is my images are with different size and different aspect ratios(but it is guaranteed that all images under one class have the same aspect ratio).

To have the same length of HOG feature, I can:

1. Resize all images to the same size.
2. Calculate the HOG parameters for each image so that they have same number of blocks and same number of cells. And thus they have the same length of HOG feature.

So which is better?

Comment: You have to test it in your task. For mine, the image rescaling preserving aspect ratio (with white stripes) works best.

Comment: Agree with old-ufo. Also, on what criteria do you define "better"? If you need to improve speed you might make it better by downsampling the larger images to lower resolution

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the images are of different size and aspect ratios, and since same class images have same aspect ratios, resizing is not a good option as it will stretch or shrink your specific class images changing their shape.

**I would suggest you to pad your images with zeros** in such a way that they all follow same size and same aspect ratio.

For e.g: image1 : 320X240, image2 : 160X120, in this case aspect ratio is same but size is different, hence pad second image with extra 160 columns and 120 rows which will make it of same size.

For e.g: image1: 320X240, image2: 320X200, in this case the aspect ratio has changed, hence pad image2 with extra 40 rows to make aspect ration the same.

In this way the aspect ratio of a particular class image remains the same.